# Common Lisp SublimeREPL

Tags: common-lisp, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I have SublimeText2 installed in OSX with SublimeREPL and it works like a charm for Ruby and Python.  However, most recently I've been wanting to pick up Common Lisp and the *"clisp REPL"* gives me the following error: **OSError(2, 'No such file or directory')**

I have tried to Google any instructions on best setup of ST2 with Common Lisp and was unsuccessful.  I would really appreciate any tips, links or instructions on getting SublimeText2 working in par with Common Lisp.

I have installed the following packages

1. SublimeREPL
2. Lispindent

Do I have to include anything in my config file to get clisp REPL working?

Comment: It seems that Sublime Text does not find `clisp` executable. Is `Common Lisp` installed in your machine, and is `clisp` in your PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of the error you're getting, I'd make sure that you've worked through all of the steps laid out in this [blog](http://www.mohiji.org/2011/01/modern-common-lisp-on-osx/) posting.

Comment: Ah-ha! it turns out clisp was not installed in my machine as mentioned by @Riccardo.  After installing it via homebrew (clisp);  the problem was solved.  Thanks for the blog post.